# Using a linked file in Assets directory - FileNotFound Exception

Tags: android, eclipse, assets

I am trying to link to an external file from a shared repository between my iOS and Android apps. This does not present a problem for iOS, but it does for Android. My current solution is to create a copy of the file from the external repository and place it in my projects Assets folder. This solution works, but is not much of a good one in my opinion and involves too many extra steps.

Using Eclipse, I am able to link to a resource. It's as simple as copying a file into my Assets folder and being prompted to either copy the file or link to the resource. If I link to the resource and try to run my app, I get a `FileNotFoundException`. If I copy the file instead, the app file is found just fine.

Ideally, I'd like to link to the file so that when I pull a new update from git then I don't need to copy the file over every single time. I'd prefer to link to the file.

Comment: Since you are doing iOS development, presumably you are using OS X. In that case, use a hardlink. BTW, official Eclipse support is over, and Android Studio/Gradle support what you want more directly.

Comment: Thank you, creating a hardlink to the file worked. If you make this an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what Eclipse uses "under the covers" for "Link here" drag-and-drop stuff. However, it is an Eclipse-ism. Android's build tools are fairly isolated from Eclipse proper, and so they won't know about those links.

Using a hardlink, or perhaps a symlink, at the OS X filesystem level should work, as both Eclipse and Android's build tools should treat it like a local file.